# GNS3: using a router as switch with it's functions

Tags: networking, router, cisco, switching

I took a look over the already asked questions and I didn't find the information I need. In case I miss the questions somehow, please accept my apologize.

I would like to know how can I use a router as switch on GNS3? Since GNS3 (at least in this moment) doesn't accept switches images, how can it be done?

Once this step is made, it is possible to use most the important switch functions? like etherchannel, trunk, multiple vlans etc.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is no true way to put switching into hardware, as of yet, that is. The TCAM's functions in L3 switches these days has yet to be perfected in software.

Secondly, there are a couple of ways to do this, but out of the three, two of them will either cost money or take some investigative work.

1. Drag the switch icon into the simulation. You can do vlan tagging as an access port, or as a trunk port. No etherchannel though. Alternatively, the 3725 Router has some switching capabilities using the 16-ESW card, however functionality is limited and syntax differs.
2. Buy VIRL from Cisco's website. It is basically an Ubuntu VM with Cisco routers, IOSvL2 (a switch essentially), ASAv, and a couple other virtual network devices. However, if you're not a student, it's a few bucks. In addition, it is subscription based

3.Upload IOU to GNS3. You will need:
-IOU image, found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/IOU%20VMs/
-Virtualbox
-License file for IOU
-GNS3 (Obviously)
-L2/L3 IOU images (The L2 images are switches)

You can find the instructions here: http://srijit.com/how-to-configure-iou-in-gns3-for-real-cisco-switching-labs/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Il helps me a lot.